# Spotlight not running application when Enter is pressed

Tags: spotlight

When searching for an application on Spotlight, the application appears, but pressing Enter does not run the application - it does nothing. I have to grab the mouse and click on the Spotlight result to run the application. This is on a Mac M1 running Ventura.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: I was working as expected on Monterrey, but now it works only intermitently on Ventura.